# Does a fire retardant plastic exist that could be fabricated to appear as long, thin grass blades/reeds?

Tags: materials

Does a cheap plastic material exists that can be fabricated to appear as long grass/reeds but is fire retardant and very durable and long-lasting when exposed to sunlight/weather? I'm basically looking for bundles of long synthetic grass leaves without fire hazard. Does this material exist?

Comment: Most thermosoftening plastics are flammable. Some thermosetting plastics might be fire resistant, but I don't know if any have the flexibility you require to resemble a blade of grass.

Comment: What data sheets for plastics have you checked?

Comment: Plastics are made fire resistant by the addition of filler. Plastics are made UV resistant by the addition of filler. Plastics are colored by the addition of filler. Plastics are made long and thin by extrusion. Colored, fire-resistant, UV resistant extrusions are possible, but setup cost for extrusion is typically large, and the filler choice makes it more difficult.